# the disk drive for /etc/fstab: is not ready

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

When I boot my machine up, I get an error:

```
The disk drive for /etc/fstab: is not ready yet or not present.
Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.
```

This error prompts me every time I boot up the computer. when i press s It allows me to sign into my account.

`/etc/fstab` content:

```
UUID="9dd9d9a0-79f1-4fed-86ba-9a1b1ea3f1cc"# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=05429edb-2387-4c86-9759-98bea3878533 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=0a96120f-3def-43b0-a41d-f9b7bf5fc920 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=9dd9d9a0-79f1-4fed-86ba-9a1b1ea3f1cc       none            swap    sw,nobootwait              0       0
UUID=722a20c4-2fcc-461a-8b70-2ec521039ddc       none            swap    sw,nobootwait              0       0
UUID=0aeac269-3265-4dea-af0f-087e800a1429       none            swap    sw,nobootwait              0       0
UUID=059f3c8a-bca9-4abb-b86a-dfb842a0b24c       none            swap    sw,nobootwait              0       0
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include the contents of the /etc/fstab file please (e.g. the output of `cat /etc/fstab` in a terminal)? it sounds like you might have a typo in there - possibly a comment that has become uncommented.

Answer (score 3):

I made a crazy mistake! When I edited `fstab`, by mistake I pasted `UUID` on the first line just before `# /etc/fstab`.

wrong:

```
UUID="9dd9d9a0-79f1-4fed-86ba-9a1b1ea3f1cc"# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
```

correct:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
```

Comment: +1 For answering your own question in a way, that may help future readers. As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!